# How to enable/disable dialog buttons (actions)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dialog

I have a helper function to create dialogs in my flutter app:

```
  Future<void> showContentDialog(BuildContext context, 
    {required Widget content, String? title, List<Tuple2<String, void Function()>>? actions}) async {
      Widget? titleWidget;
      if (title != null) {
        titleWidget = Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        );
      }
    
      var dialogActions = <Widget>[];
      if (actions != null) {
        dialogActions.addAll(
          actions.map(
            (a) => TextButton(
                child: Text(a.item1),
                onPressed: () {
                  a.item2();
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: titleWidget,
          content: SizedBox(width: ThemeHelpers.maxPopupWidth, child: content),
          actions: dialogActions,
        ),
      );
    }
```

There is another similar one that is used on Apple devices that uses equivalent widgets.

I can easyly manage state on the content portion of the dialog by wrapping it in a StatefulBuilder, but how can I enable and disable the dialog buttons (the actions passed to the AlertDialog) builder depending on content state?

My first idea was to add another a ValueNotifier parameter to the action builders and wrap them in ValueListenerBuilders but that didn't work.

Do I have any way of doing that other than including the actions as buttons inside the content (were I can easyly manage their state)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass null on onPressed to disable the button state. While it is not clear from where you like to controll the state, you can use ValueNotifier, and it work for all widget

```dart
  final ValueNotifier<bool> enableButton = ValueNotifier(false);
  Future<void> showContentDialog(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: SizedBox(
          width: 222,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("A"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  enableButton.value = !enableButton.value;
                },
                child: Text("toggleButtonState"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
            valueListenable: enableButton,
            builder: (context, value, child) => ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: value ? () {} : null,
              child: Text("BTN"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I had already tried that without success, at the time I had failed to see the reason why: I was trying to change the ValueNotifier state from inside a TextFormField validation and that was causing an exception that was being hidden, so I just assumed it would not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

In content add column and add dialog widgets in it

```dart
await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: titleWidget,
          content: Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children : [
              SizedBox(width: ThemeHelpers.maxPopupWidth, child: content),
          dialogActions,
           ]
          )
        ),
      );
```